# Pushforward of the vector field $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ by exponential, i.e $exp_{*}\dfrac{d}{dx}$ = $x\dfrac{d}{dx}$ on $R_{+}^*$

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, pushforward

I'm trying to proof the following statement coming from a book:

"Pushforward of the vector field $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ by exponential, i.e $exp_{*}\dfrac{d}{dx}$ = $x\dfrac{d}{dx}$ on $R_{+}^*$"

The only statement I have in my possession is that for $\phi$ a diffeomorphism between $M \rightarrow N$ , and $X$ a vector field, (which is a section of $TM$), on has the following property:

$\forall x$ in $N$

$(\phi_{*}X)(x) = d_{\phi^{-1}(x)}\phi$ . $X(\phi^{-1}(x))$

Hence, I tried applying the formula, $exp_{*}\dfrac{d}{dx}(x)$  =  $(d_{\exp^{-1}(x)}\exp)$ . $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\exp^{-1}(x))$ = $d_{\ln(x)}\exp$ . $\dfrac{d}{dx}(\ln(x))$ 
= $d_{\ln(x)}\exp$ . $\dfrac{1}{x}$ = $exp(1/x)$

But if the result I'm trying to prove is right, I should have that $\forall x$ in $R_{+}^*$
$x\dfrac{d}{dx}(x)$ = $x$

Am I missing something more conceptual ? Thank you in advance for explanation

Comment: I'm confused about the formula $(\phi_{*}X)(x) = d_{\phi^{-1}(x)}\phi$ . $X(\phi^{-1}(x))$. Shouldn't there be a function $f\in C^\infty(N)$ somewhere since the vector field $X$ is a derivative?

Comment: Isn't the definition of the pushforward of $\phi : M \to N$ of the vector field $X$ on $M$ given by $(\phi_* X)f := X(f\circ\phi^{-1})$ for every smooth function $f$ on $N$? Note that $f\circ\phi^{-1}$ is a function on $M$ so we can apply $X$ on that.

Comment: In accordance to my courses on differentiable manifold, $\phi_{*}X$ is a vector field. So you must apply $x \in M$ to it. For me the notation of the associated derivative of $\phi_{*}X$ writes, $\mathcal{L}_{(\phi_{*}X)}: f \rightarrow \mathcal{L}_{(\phi_{*}X)}(f) = (\mathcal{L}_{X}(f\circ \phi)) \circ \phi^{-1}$. It's just a difference of notation.

Comment: @md2perpe If $\varphi \colon M \to N$ is a diffeomorphism and $X$ is a vector field on $M$, the pushforward of $X$ by $\varphi$, denoted by $\varphi_* X$, is the vector field on $N$ which is obtained by transporting $X$ through $\varphi$. The formula given by OP, namely $(\varphi_* X)(p) = \mathrm{d}\varphi( \varphi^{-1}(p)) \cdot X(\varphi^{-1}(p))$ for $p\in N$, is the good one. It seems messy but in fact is a very natural definition, since $\mathrm{d}\varphi(\varphi^{-1}(p)) \colon T_{\varphi^{-1}(p)}M \to T_pN$ is a linear isomorphism

Comment: AFAIK there are a couple of definitions of vector space. One is as a derivation, i.e. $X$ acts on functions and gives functions, and it satisfies $X(fg) = (Xf) g + f (Xg).$ Another one is a section of $TM$ in which case it is a map taking a point $p\in M$ and giving a vector in $T_pM.$ When g0dLose writes "vector field $\frac{d}{dx}$" it seems like the definition as a derivation is used. On the other hand he also writes "$X$ a vector space, (which is a section of $TM$)". But I guess that there is a natural isomorphism between the two definitions.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes, there is a canonical isomorphism between these two notions, and there is nothing wrong with saying "$\frac{d}{dx}$ is a vector field" when meaning "a section of the tangent bundle": in differential geometry, we always write "Let $X = \sum_i X^i \partial_i$" be a vector field"! I agree this seems a bit weird at the first sight.

Comment: Which book is this from, please? It'd be nice to check a couple of things there if possible.

Comment: @rych "Introduction aux variétés différentielles" of Jacques Lafontaine

Answer (score 3):

The pushforward of a vector field is well-defined just by a diffeomorphism (or in a Lie group), that is, if $\varphi :M\to N$ is such diffeomorphism then $\varphi _*:\mathfrak{X}(M)\to \mathfrak{X}(N)$, where $\mathfrak{X}(D)$ is the space of smooth vector fields on $D$.

The pushforward is defined by

$$
(\varphi _*X)_{\varphi (p)}f=X_p(f\circ \varphi )
$$

In this case if $\varphi :\mathbb{R}\to (0,\infty ),\, x\mapsto e^x$ you have

$$
\left(\exp_*\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)_rf=\left .\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right|_{\ln r}(f \circ \exp)=(f'\circ \exp)(\ln r)\exp'(\ln r)=r\cdot f'(r)=\left .t\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{r}f
$$

where $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathfrak{X}((0,\infty ))$ and $f$ is any smooth function in $(0,\infty )$.

Comment: First, thanks for explanation, to me the pushforward was defined only on M, not on function. To me the "associated derivation of the pushforward" was defined on function; Which I denote by $\mathcal{L}_{X}$ for X a field, (and so for the case of the pushforward, replace $X$ by $\varphi_{*}X$.)

Comment: Secondly: According to your notation: $(\varphi_{*}X)_{p}(f) = X_{\varphi^{-1}(p)}(f\circ \varphi)$

On the other hand, according to my course: $X_{x}(f) = d_{x}f.X_{x}$

Hence: $X_{\varphi^{-1}(p)}(f\circ \varphi) = d_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}(f\circ \varphi).X_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}$.

Replacing by non abstract vector field and diffeomorphism one has:

$d_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}(f\circ \varphi).X_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} = f'(x)x.\dfrac{d}{dx}(ln(x)) = f'(x)x. 1/x = f'(x) = \dfrac{d}{dt}∣_{x}f $ What's wrong with what I've done ?

Comment: this $d_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}(f\circ \varphi).X_{\varphi^{-1}(x)} = f'(x)x.\dfrac{d}{dx}(ln(x))$ is wrong, as $\exp^{-1}(x)=\ln x$ is a point, not a function, you dont differentiate a point, what you differentiate is $f$

Comment: The formula comes from a book, it's 100% true, the fact is that in what I wrote, $X$ is a vector field to me, hence a section of $TM$ and so $X_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}$ belongs to $T_{\varphi^{-1}(x)}M$

Answer (score 1):

$\def\R{\mathbb{R}}%$@Masacroso's is the answer, but I think we could also use the Fréchet derivative of the map between two copies of $\R$, $Dexp: \R_1\to\R_2$, $Dexp_x=e^x=y$; for an arbitrary $h\in \R_1$, $Dexp_x(h)=e^xh\in \R_2.$

The map derivative, on the other hand, is a pushforward of **tangent** vectors. We can use what's called canonical identification or natural isomorphism: $g_1: T\R_1\to\R_1$ and $g_2: T\R_2\to\R_2$. The relation formula (see @levap's answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2158705/73934) for example) between the pushforward and the Fréchet derivative of our map $exp$ is

$$exp_{*p}=g_2^{-1}\circ Dexp\circ g_1:T\R_1\to T\R_2$$
And so we have
$exp_{*x}(h\tfrac{d}{dx})=[g_2^{-1}\circ Dexp\circ g_1](h\tfrac{d}{dx})=[g_2^{-1}\circ Dexp_x](h)=g_2^{-1}(e^xh)=(e^xh)\tfrac{d}{dy}$,

where $\tfrac{d}{dy}$ is the basis vector on the $T\R_2$. Taking $h=1$ we finally have
$$exp_{*x}(\tfrac{d}{dx})=y\tfrac{d}{dy}$$